# Can Sails query two tables at the same time?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I am trying to use Sails query language to query two tables, with Postgresql as the database.

I have two tables 'Person' and 'Pet'.

For 'Person', its model is:

```
id: { type: 'integer', primaryKey }
namePerson: { type: 'string' }
age: { type: 'integer' }
```

For 'Pet', its model is:

```
id: { type: 'integer', primaryKey }
owner: { model: 'Person' }
namePet: { type: 'string' }
```

I want to find all the pets who are owned by people younger than 12, and I want to do it in a single query. Is that possible?

I only know how to do it in two queries. First, find all the people who are younger than 12:

```
Person.find({age: {'<', 12}}).exec(function (err, persons) {..};
```

Then, find all the pets owned by them:

```
Pet.find({owner: persons}).exec( ... )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need here [one-to-many association](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many) (one person can have several pets).

Your person should be associated with pets:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        // ...
        pets:{
            collection: 'pet',
            via: 'owner'
        }
    }
}
```

Your pets should be associated with person:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        // ...
        owner:{
            model:'person'
        }
    }
}
```

You can still find user by age criteria:

```
Person
    .find({age: {'<', 12}})
    .exec(function (err, persons) { /* ... */ });
```

To fetch user with his pets you should populate association:

```
Person
    .find({age: {'<', 12}})
    .populate('pets')
    .exec(function(err, persons) { 
        /* 
        persons is array of users with given age. 
        Each of them contains array of his pets
        */ 
    });
```

Sails allow you to perform multiple population in one query like:

```
Person
    .find({age: {'<', 12}})
    .populate('pets')
    .populate('children')
    // ...
```

But nested populations is not exist, issue [discussion here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/308).

Comment: thanks for you answer. It explains very well. One more question. I found that the query: Person.find({age: {'<', 12}}).populate('pets') also returns persons which no pets, i.e. { ... pets: [ ] ... }. It is possible to just return persons with at least one pet? Thanks.